# Setting Firebase Database Security Rules For Simple App

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase for a very simple purpose-- just to create a real-time button for WordPress that disappears on-click. There are no users/ authentication.

How can I make security rules that prevent someone from tampering with the database, but allow the button to work? The simple way I know how is to set the security `write": false`, but then the button won't work as the Firebase variables cannot be altered/updated. [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) seems to be more directed at apps with users, but does seem to mention being able to set limits on read/write/etc for certain paths.

Perhaps I can make it so that only the used Firebase paths/variables used can be updated?

```js
var database = firebase.database();
//firebase queue

//**************
///timer fb
let timestamp;
let now = new Date().getTime();
let endTimeRef = firebase.database().ref("server");
let endTime;
let minutes;
let secondsDisplay;
let distance= endTime-now;
let buttonDisplay=  document.getElementById("queue");
let timerDisplay =  document.getElementById("timer_fb");
let message=        document.getElementById("timer_div");

function displayTimer(){
  
   minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
   secondsDisplay= Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
      
   let s;
   if (minutes >= 1 || secondsDisplay >= 1) {
      if (minutes >= 1 && secondsDisplay >= 10) {
        s = "Time Until Next Person: " + minutes + ":" + secondsDisplay;
      } else if (minutes >= 1) {
        s = "Time Until Next Person: " + minutes + ":0" + secondsDisplay;
      } else {
        s = "Time Until Next Person: " + secondsDisplay + "s";
      }
    } else {
      s = "";
    }
    document.getElementById("timer_fb").innerHTML = s;
  
}

function setTimer() {
    let interval = setInterval(function() {
      
      now = new Date().getTime();
      distance= endTime-now;
      
      //update timer display
      displayTimer();
           
      if (distance <= 0) {  
        buttonDisplay.style.display = "block";
        timer_div.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("timer_div").innerHTML = "This session is open!";
        clearInterval(interval);
        timerState.set('off');
        endTimeRef.set(0);
           }
    }, 1000);
  }


//display timer
   

//state machine
let timerState = firebase.database().ref("timerState");

let timer;

timerState.on("value", function(snapshot) {
   
    timer= snapshot.val();
    if(timer == "on"){   
      buttonDisplay.style.display = "none"; 
      message.style.display = "none";
      endTimeRef.once("value", function(snap) {
      let endStamp  = snap.val();
        console.log("stored button snap value check: ", snap.val());
      now = new Date().getTime();  
     endTime= endStamp +100000;
     distance= endTime-now;    
            
     //show display right after button is pressed   
   displayTimer();
   setTimer(); 
    }); 
  }   
});



//********
//*****on click handler
document.getElementById("queue").onclick = function() {
  //hide button 
  buttonDisplay.style.display = "none"; 
  message.style.display = "none";
  
  //set time button comes back
     now = new Date().getTime();
     endTime= now + 100000;
     endTimeRef.set(now);
     
  //firebase state machine
  timerState.set('on');
  //setInterval handler, used for timer/countdown
  //need to wrap interval in function so that it can be reused 
};
```

Comment: Your question is kind of vague, and you're kind of asking two questions here, one in the title and one in the body.  You might want to narrow down your question to something specific about the rules you're trying to write.  Or, if you're actually looking for a conversation (because you don't have a discrete question yet), try posting to a discussion forum such as Reddit or firebase-talk Google group.

Comment: Thanks, I will try clarifying and rephrasing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you mean only the used Firebase paths/variables used can be updated?
But if you are not using authentication how do you distinguish which users able to access this value which users can not.Or you want make all user can read this value only in some case can modify?

Comment: I have a button that, when clicked, cannot be clicked for another 1 mintute and 30 seconds. Anyone that sees that button should be allowed to click it. What I do not want it someone to hack the firebase and alter the database code responsible for this timer. My understanding is that since I have set the rules so that anyone can read or write to the database that is is currently possible and would like to prevent this.